# redirect facebook visit to another webpage

Tags: iptables, facebook, redirect

I'm looking for a way to redirect visits to facebook to another website. It's to stop a child from wasting all his time on facebook.
We can't use extensions because they are simple to disable so I'm looking for something along the lines of the hosts file from windows which redirects all visits to a ip to another ip.

I know of iptables but I can't quite figure out how to redirect all visits to facebook to another webpage.

I'm using ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: It seems you need some kind of Parental Control. Check this out, it may fit what you need: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ParentalControls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your host file:

`sudo gedit /etc/hosts`

Attach the ip adress of google to facebook:

```
193.95.12.39 www.facebook.com
193.95.12.39 facebook.com
```

Save and reconnect